# Split String if it contains a word from the List

Tags: java, java-8, split

I am reading a text file line by line and I want to split each line if they contain a word that is present in a specific List.

Example:

```
String str1 = BuraBua is the Place I live in.
String str2 = New York is the Place I live.
```

Now I have a List of String like : `List li = Arrays.asList("BuraBura", "New York");`

I want something like:

```
String[] strList = str1.split(// if str1 contains a word from li then split on that basis);
```

**Any suggestions??**

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to split on space but I get wrong when I get New york as New York combined is a state.

Comment: “split on that basis” is a very fuzzy problem description. What is the intended result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind a simple. You can do it by iterating whitelist/keys.

#### Java 8 and later:

Don't need to use `filters`, `maps` and `collectors`. It's redundant, because you will get list of lists. Better to use simple `forEach` stream by iterating keys.

**Method:**

```java
private final List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("apple", "orange");

public List<String> getSplitted(String text) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    keys.forEach(key -> {
       if (text.toLowerCase().contains(key.toLowerCase()))
            parts.addAll(Arrays.asList(text.split(key)));
    });
    return parts;
}
```

---

#### Older Java:

Use simple `for` iterator

**Method**

```java
private final List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("apple", "orange");

public List<String> getSplitted(String text) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String key : keys) {
        if (text.toLowerCase().contains(key.toLowerCase()))
            parts.addAll(Arrays.asList(text.split(key)));
    }
    return parts;
}
```

---

#### Test (groovy):

> ```
> def "Splitter test"() {
>    given:
>        def text = "I like orange very much. Because orange is very delicious"
>    when:
>        def result = new Splitter().getSplitted(text)
>    then:
>        result == ["I like ", " very much. Because ", " is very delicious"]
> }
> ```

***Comment if your needs is different.***

Comment: There are fundamental problems using a check like `contains(key.toLowerCase())`, followed by an operation as `text.split(key)` that is using the string as-is, case sensitive. What is the intended outcome of checking with `toLowercase()`? When the string is `"Apple"` and the text contains `Apple`, the test will fail. You are also not caring for “words”. Think of what will happen when the text contains “apples”. And what will happen when the text contains both, “apple” and “orange”…

Answer (score -1):

```
List<List<String>> lo = li.stream()
    .filter(str -> str1.contains(str))
    .map(str -> { return Arrays.asList(str1.split(str)); })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: If your input contains multiple split string then this has to be further modified. In case that happens to be the case, then you can try for loop. Hope it gives some path. Thanks

Comment: A combination of formatting and the use a block when a simple lambda would do makes this code more or less unreadable.